# facebook auto re-login from cookie php

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My website uses Facebook connect for login and the session lifetime on my server is 3600.

I'm using [Client-Side Flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) (javascript) redirect to login.php, and login.php retrieve cookies (set by javascript) to get access token.

However, if a user is idled over 3600 seconds, the session on my server expires. ($_SESSION['uid'] does not exists.)
How can my login.php check the user has already logged in Facebook(not my app) or not?

The solution I'm using is to redirect the user to my javascript page, and "onStatus function" would be automatically trigged by facebook.

I'm searching for a solution which can all be done with login.php to automatically relogin my website if he or she has logged in Facebook (without redirecting to javascript page). Is is possible?

javascript:

```
FB.init({appId: 'MY_APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    onStatus(response);
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', onStatus);
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', reloadPage);
});

function onStatus(response) {
    if (response.session) {
        window.location.href = '/login?fb';
    }
}

function reloadPage(response) {
    if (response.session) {
        window.location.href = '/login?fb';
    }
}
```

PHP (for login):

```
function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $app_secret) {
  $args = array();
  if(!isset($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id]))
      return false;
  parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id], '\\"'), $args);
  ksort($args);
  $payload = '';
  foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != 'sig') {
      $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
    }
  }
  if (md5($payload . $app_secret) != $args['sig']) {
      return false;
  }
  return $args;
}

$cookie = get_facebook_cookie(MY_APP_ID, MY_APP_SECRET);

if($cookie){
    if($result = @file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token=".$cookie['access_token'])){
        $result = json_decode($result, true);
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $result['id'];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out a way to do so. To iframe the following page in all pages.

When the access token gave by facebook through cookie expires, page in iframe auto refresh.
And FB.init() would set up a new access token(cookie) for my app.

In my php files, just check the cookies as first connected.

fb_keepalive.html:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/zh_TW/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.init({appId: 'APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    onStatus(response);
});

function onStatus(response) {
    if (response.session) {
        var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
        var expires = response['session']['expires'] * 1000;
        if(expires - timestamp >= 0){
            setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload();}, expires - timestamp);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: and for passing parameters into the iframe you can look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663396/passing-url-parameters-to-iframe-using-jquery-or-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Im still a newb to FB connect and that whole process but I wanted to put my 2 cents in. I have seen a few sites strictly built on users having FB so them being logged in or not to FB applies to the particular sites I mention. I have noticed if I am logged in on FB and have connected with those sites in the past then I am automatically logged back into said site same logic applied if im not logged in.

That said I assume this means FB has a recognizable cookie that can be detected somewhere, where if detected you can likely use it in your script to get the users to be auto logged in past that 3600 mark. I know from twitter and linkedin that they have user auth tokens that identify each user that can ultimately be stored in a DB and reused later So I think maybe your going to want to look into that a bit more with FB as Im sure that has to be the case with FB as well. Where you store this token thats associated with a user where you can find that if the cookie previously mentioned was found, then check for that auth token. Im sorry if this doesnt make much sense Im running on fumes here. If i was any better with the FB stuff I'd try to offer more help but I am in the very basic stages of understanding how I can interact with FB and a non fb site.

Comment: It's not a problem to auto login using client-side flow by javascript. The situation I encountered is as following: A user came to our site. After 3600 seconds, he/she submit a form in that page, however, the session has expired and our scripts can not recognize who the user is. If we redirect the user to a auto-login page, we can't get POST datas after auto re-login.

Comment: Ok, so another option might be even though its in the essence of the opposite that your trying to achieve in a matter of speaking. Is typically you would assume after an hour of inactivity the user has walked away, lost power, is watching a movie, whatever. With that they could be at a public pc, which is why it expires to begin with. That said why not on a timer that resets with activity have it count down to 0 from 3600 and when it reaches 0 automatically redirect them to the login with a message stating logged out due to inactivity. This way you dont fight an uphill battle keeping them in

Answer (score 0):

While keeping the client side flow, you can use the Facebook PHP SDK ([see on github](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)) for dealing with the user session.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(...);

// Get the User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

`$user` not null means that the user is logged in Facebook and authenticated. You don't need anymore the PHP you gave here (`get_facebook_cookie` and stuff) : it is all included in the Facebook PHP SDK. It should be enough for you.

---

Going further : if you want to make API calls for that user.

`$user` not null does not mean you have a valid access token for this user. One way to test if you have a valid access token is the try to make an API call :

```
$isvalid;

try { 
  $facebook->api('/me');
  $isvalid = true;
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  $isvalid = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't help. When the access token(cookie) gave by facebook expires, it says not connected.

Comment: If the access token expire, isn't it because the user logged out of Facebook ? In that case, you can keep him logged in and keep making API calls. Do you know about the offline_access permission ? Facebook issue an access token that never expires. Might help you.

Comment: The user is still inside facebook but the cookie expires for apps soon.  I've considered offline_access, but it is not the thing I need.  Because my account session on my server expires, I don't know who the client is. However, I can save the offline access to cookie to solve the problem, but not a good solution.